# Return multiple values from a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to return multiple links in python, but can't figure out how. If I print `link_href`I get all of the links, but when I return, I get only the first link and the app quits. Can anyone help me please?

```
def main():
def get_links():
    offset = 0     
    while int(offset) < 990:
        url = f"https://krmeni.cz/kniha?offset={str(offset)}"
        page_content = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content.text, "html.parser")
        file_path = "chatbot_data.csv"
        offset += 10
        for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'white-btn'}):
            title = link.string
            link_href = link.get("href")
            if link.string == "přidat odpověď":
                continue
            else:
                return link_href


for link_href in get_links():
    answer_url = f"https://krmeni.cz{get_links()}"
    print(answer_url)
```

Comment: Because you return as soon as you get to the `else` statement. Instead you need to add your hrefs to a list, then return that list outside the loop.

Comment: If you want multiple values returned add them to a list and return the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code exits on the fist if and else statement.

```
  if link.string == "přidat odpověď":
      continue
  else:
      return link_href
```

Initialize a list before the for loop and append link_href in else statement. The after completion of execution of for loop, return the list.Like this.

```
    link_list = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'white-btn'}):
        title = link.string
        link_href = link.get("href")
        if link.string == "přidat odpověď":
            continue
        else:
            link_list.append(link_href)
    return link_list
```

Or make a generator,

```
  for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'white-btn'}):
        title = link.string
        link_href = link.get("href")
        if link.string == "přidat odpověď":
            continue
        else:
            yield link_href
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop exits after finding the first link. Use a list comprehension:

```
return [link.get('href')
        for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'white-btn'})
        if link.string == 'pridat odpoved']
```

This returns a list containing the links you need.

Answer (score 0):

just use generator function **yield** instead of **return**

```
def main():
def get_links():
    offset = 0     
    while int(offset) < 990:
        url = f"https://krmeni.cz/kniha?offset={str(offset)}"
        page_content = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content.text, "html.parser")
        file_path = "chatbot_data.csv"
        offset += 10
        for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'white-btn'}):
            title = link.string
            link_href = link.get("href")
            if link.string == "přidat odpověď":
                continue
            else:
                yield link_href


for link_href in get_links():
    answer_url = f"https://krmeni.cz{get_links()}"
    print(answer_url)
```